# Apache vhost redirects to another vhost

Tags: apache, vhosts

I've set up two projects for two different vhosts and the problem is that no matter which URL I try to open, I'll be redirected to the first one.

Windows hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 myfirst-project.local
127.0.0.1 mysecond-project.local
```

Apache vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost myfirst-project.local:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:\projects\first"
    ServerName myfirst-project.local
    ErrorLog "logs/first-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/first-access.log" common
 
    <Directory "D:\projects\first">
      Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost mysecond-project.local:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:\projects\second"
    ServerName mysecond-project.local
    ErrorLog "logs/second-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/second-access.log" common
 
    <Directory "D:\projects\second">
      Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If I open mysecond-project.local on the browser, I'll be immediately redirected to myfirst-project.local

I have no idea why is it happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
httpd -S
```

To determine where/how your virtualhosts were actually being loaded. If your Apache version is 2.2 or earlier you have to add this line before the VirtualHost definitions:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Comment: I tried it, didn't work. Now I literally deleted the first virtual host from the vhosts file and also the hosts file, restarted the PC & xampp-apache and still redirecting to that non-existing vhost.